# Unable to get revit filemeta data or see revit model in 3d viewer for forge modelderivative API

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have been using the model derivative api endpoints to extact data from forge but are currently having issues extracting meta data when uploading specifically Revit files.

Our process goes:

1. Auth
2. Upload a model in chunks  https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/{bucketKey}/objects/{objectName}/resumable
3. Create upload job  https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job
4. Get translation the process  https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{encodedUrn}/manifest
5. Get the object from the forge https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{encodedUrn}/metadata

Current we are we receive a 200 response from step 5 with and empty meta information so we cannot extract anything.

When we load the 3D viewer (versions 6.0 and 4.0) the viewer calls the https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/

When

```
"messages": [
            {
                "type": "error",
                "code": "Revit-UnsupportedFileType",
                "message": "<message>The file is not a Revit file or is not a supported version.</message>"
            },
            {
                "type": "error",
                "message": "Possibly recoverable warning exit code from extractor: -536870935",
                "code": "TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure"
            }
        ],
```

It was converted from an ifc format if that helps in any way.
We have tried this file in 360 and in forge with both revit and ifc before and translation has worked.  I can provide a urn also.

Comment: can you share the URN? Would you also have the URN you uploaded to 360?

Comment: Great thanks @AugustoGoncalves

Uploaded urn: `dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Ymltc3VwcGx5LXNwYWNlcy1kZXYvNWM2YzM3YWQyNWNiNDBkYjljY2MwZWIxZTdjNWZkODdDcmF3Zm9yZF9Mb2dpc3RpY3NfSGFsbC5ydnQ`

360 URN - is either 

`dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5mb2xkZXI6Y28uNTlFWTFFdGhRdjZ4T2hLY25weG9jUQ`
or 
`dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpkbS5saW5lYWdlOlJDS0xsdElvUlo2Q1NPZ0RkZEk2SFE`

Both were part of the url (can provide this as well if needed). After investigation we can see that the translation endpoints returns "failed" as well. We hadn't captured this previously.

Comment: thanks, I'll check the URN. Meanwhile, you said IFC, but the urn decodes to a .rvt file... did you convert them using Revit desktop? Do you know the translation also works for IFC file? (i.e. no need to convert them)

Comment: Hi yes we knew. Apparently the ifc was used as a reference in Revit, but the model was completely redone there. This was so we could add BIM objects to the model and get BOM data and apparently our experience is with Revit (im a dev not an architect so apologies if muddle terms).  I believe its either 2018 or 2019 rvt version. Thanks for you help

Comment: Hi @AugustoGoncalves understand you are probably busy, but have you seen any issues with the upload/translation or know when you will have a chance to look at this? just so we can plan ahead. We've tried with a variety of files sizes (less than the minimum chunk size) but still get the same error. We are now going back over the examples and checking our chunking implementation with the SDK to make sure we are not making any silly errors.

Comment: hi @Glenit, sorry my delay on this, I started digging but could not find a log describing the problem, I'm suspecting problems on upload, but to really check I would need one of your testing files... can you share a non-confidential file at forge.help[at]autodesk.com?

Comment: Absolutely ill do that

Comment: We think we found an issue with the chunking process - part of the stream was cut off, and so the file would have been corrupted. @AugustoGoncalves Ive emailed the support thread as well

Answer (score 1):

As reported by @Glenit, it was missing some pieces on the resumable upload. For reference, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51788083/4838205) points out some samples on it.