# Forge - Revit-UnsupportedFileType

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I’m trying to integrate Forge viewer with my sample application and facing some issues.

Below are the steps I tried to achieve my goal.

1. Registered an app by creating a new account and generated “client ID” and “secret key” (success).
2. Generate Oauth token for further API calls (success).
3. Create a new bucket storage (success).
4. Upload model to the bucket and create URN for the model (success).
5. Design data for model translation (this is the step where our uploaded model will be translated to SVF) (success).
6. Check status of translated file. (success response but with error message as given below).

"messages": 
[
                {
                    "type": "error",
                    "code": "Revit-UnsupportedFileType",
                    "message": "The file is not a Revit file or is not a supported version."
                },
                {
                    "type": "error",
                    "message": "Possibly recoverable warning exit code from extractor: -536870935",
                    "code": "TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure"
                }
            ],

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to upload & view the file using the [public viewer](http://viewer.autodesk.com/)? If so, most likely your upload routine (step 4) is corrupting the file. In this case, are you using resumable upload?

Samples for resumable upload:

- [C#](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/c-resumable-upload-file-forge-sdk)
- [Nodejs](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/nailing-large-files-uploads-forge-resumable-api)

Comment: Yes I was able to load the model in public viewer, as you mentioned step 4 was corrupting the file. Thank you for your reference links.