# GET :urn/metadata returns an empty list

Tags: autodesk-forge

I tried the method in the object with this RVT urn: `dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLk1HQm5UX2MtVFhteHRzZzJZY2NXR3c_dmVyc2lvbj0x`

I get this response with status code 200 `{"data":{"type":"metadata","metadata":[]}}`

I cannot extract properties using the model derivative API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi we had a similar error where meta was empty.

This was because the upload had succeeded (we got a urn) but the translation had failed and getting the meta information on failed translation just returned an empty meta repsonse. This was specifically with revit files.

If you check the manifest endpoint with that urn do you see and revit file translation error?

Comment: Thanks, I checked the manifest, you are right the status says it has failed. The weird thing is that Revit-UnsupportedFileType error code that I don't understand. When I tried an IFC it worked just fine.

Comment: We have an ongoing support issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770589/unable-to-get-revit-filemeta-data-or-see-revit-model-in-3d-viewer-for-forge-mode

I've seen this error both reported as single upload and in our case in the chunked upload.  Augusto Goncalves may be able to shed some light

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves unfortunately no

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves, thanks for your help! I was able to resolve the issue, I was uploading a file with an extra 140 bytes due to the method I was using call the PUT. When I changed it to a stream it worked.[link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads)